# How do I stay in a for loop's element until a condition is met?

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop around a list in python to use as parameters to send to a site.
However, sometimes, the request is returning time-out errors. How would I be able to stay in the current loop until the source is met?

```
import requests
URL = 'https://name.com/'
Names = ['Bob', 'Andy', 'Mike']

for i in Names:
    callback = requests.get(url=URL, params=i)
    source = callback.text

    if i in source:
        print("Found it")

    else:
        #retry
```

The list is already filtered beforehand in order to make sure it is suitable to be inputted as a parameter. So what I'm trying to say is the contents in the list will always provide a valid source.

Comment: Use a nested loop.

Comment: @VictorRuiz That will exit the loop, not stay on the current element.

Comment: else: ```break```

Comment: If you're getting timeouts why not just set `timeout` higher for `requests.get`? You don't want this to go on forever it it's timing out for a valid reason, you'll end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: You want to handle failures, instead of infinitely retrying, but however you do that, you can hide the retry logic in a function, like so -- for name in Names: check_name(url, name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. Like this:

```
import requests
URL = 'https://name.com/'
Names = ['Bob', 'Andy', 'Mike']

for i in Names: 

    while True:

        callback = requests.get(url=URL, params=i)
        source = callback.text

        if i in source:
            print("Found it")
            break
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can omit the `found` variable entirely. Loop over `while True:`, and when you currently do `found = True`, just `break`.

Comment: Sure, just thought It'd be more expressive this way. I'll edit though.